# Count number of ranges into a serie of dates, also a range, from a table

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables:

In the first, `tbl_vacations`trough a form are inserted the vacations of the workers, with this format:

```
DNI          Date1          Date2
---------    ---------      ------------
1234567      2016-01-01     2016-01-25
22222222     2016-01-05     2016-01-17
1234569      2016-01-10     2016-01-25
1231234      2016-01-07     2016-01-31
```

On the second table, `calendar_table` , I have a serie of dates, from 2014-01-01 until 2044-12-31

```
dt
-------
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
2014-01-03
and so on
```

I want to select two dates from `calendar_table` and count the number of days from tbl_vacations that falls into the range of selected dates, for instance:

```
daten           count of vacations
-------         ---------------------
2016-01-01      1
2016-01-02      1
2016-01-04      1
2016-01-05      2
2016-01-06      2
2016-01-07      3
2016-01-08      3
2016-01-09      3
2016-01-10      4
2016-01-11      4
2016-01-12      4
```

My idea is to show this data into a chart.

How should be the query required?

Comment: what are your ideas on that matter?

Comment: to fill a chart with the number of vacations given each day of the range selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would left join calendar_table on tbl_vacations to get all dates from calendar_table, even those which do not have any vacation days, count the records where DNI is set. I would also restrict the date range in the where criteria, since you are probably niot interested in how many holidays are scheduled for 2044 at the moment:

```
select calendar_table.daten, count(DNI)
from calendar_table
left join tbl_vacations on calendar_table.daten between tbl_vacations.date1 and tbl_vacations.date2
where calendar_table.daten between ... and ...
group by calendar_table.daten
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where calendar_table.daten between '2016-03-01' and '2016-03-31'

Comment: LIMIT 0, 25' at line 5

Comment: Mixed up the order of where and group by, but you could have checked this out yourself. Corrected the code.

Comment: Sorry, not used to sql yet.

Comment: Just perfect!! TNX